# How to check if a customer's visit overlaps a one hour time block

Tags: excel, time, block

Our restaurant has 20 tables. We want to understand how many maximum tables have customers at any give hour. We want to allocate the staff accordingly, find out our busiest hours, etc.

- Customers can come in between 10am and 6am (the restaurant is open overnight)
- Customers stay a variable amount of time
- Have 6 months data
- Have to find max number of tables occupied for each 1 hour interval (9am - 10am, 10am - 11am, etc.) for each day of 6 months
- The result will have 6 months * 30 (~ 180) rows signifying one row per day
- Ideally the result should look like:

| Date | 9am - 10am | 10 - 11am | ......and so on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aug 1 | 14. | 18 |  |
| Aug 2. | 12. | 14 |  |
| Aug 3. | 9. | 10 |  |

What would be the best way to do this?

I am stuck at summing up the totals for each day. Cant find a formula to find if a customer's length of stay is part of the set time block: ***checking if any part of the customer's visit falls within the 1 hour time block***.

Created a table like:

| Time In | Time Out | 9am - 10am | 10am - 11am |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10am | 12pm | No | Yes |
| 2am | 4am | No | No |

And then planning to calculate the total yes s for each day. But cant get to the exact formula that works for yes and no for customer stays that go overnight!

any other way to do this? Am I on the wrong track?

Th RAW data looks like:

| Time In | Time Out | Customer ID | (Other irrelevant fields) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10am | 12pm | 123 |  |
| 2am | 4am | 456 |  |
| 11pm | 3am | 123 |  |

One customer can also have more than one row since customers come back and it's 6 months of data.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an example of what the raw data looks like as this will affect which formula to suggest. Also in your second table, should 10am - 11am be a 'Yes' for the first row?

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes useful to start with a simplified version of a problem and to build out from there.

So starting with a simplified day of (say) 8 hours, call the start of that day time 0 and the end time 8 with the end of the first hour being time 1, the end of the second being time 2, etc.

The customer data for that day will be given by the times of entry and exit so we can take some example data as (say)

| Time of Entry | Time of Exit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 8 |

Consider first, the entries. The following table of 1's and 0's shows for each of the 9 customers above whether or not they entered at a particular time.

[image: Entry data]

The body of the table is generated using the [dynamic array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)
`=N(A3:A11=B2:J2)`
The total row is calculated using the `SUM` function and shows the profile of entries over the 8 hour period.

A similar exercise can be performed on the exit data.

Combining the totals for entries and exits, yields the profile of persons in attendance throughout the 8 hours as shown next.

[image: Combining entry and exit results]

The row labelled "Net" is simply the "Entries" less the "Exits" and "Persons" is the "Net" value accumulated along the row.

**Reducing it to a single formula**

Naming the entry data (in `A3:A11`) as `Entry`, the exit data as `Exit` and the time values (in B2:J2) as `Time`, the entry totals showing in row 12 can be written using the formula:

`=BYCOL(N(Entry=Time),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c)))`

Provided the `Exit` values are similarly organised as a column range, the exit totals will similarly be

`=BYCOL(N(Exit=Time),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c)))`

and clearly the former can be subtracted from the latter to give the "Net" values.

The `SCAN` function can be wrapped around the "Net" values to accumulate them into the "Persons" profile, as follows

`=SCAN(0, BYCOL(N(Entry=...) - BYCOL(N(Exit=...), LAMBDA(a,v,a+v))`

This provides a single function for creating the "Persons" profile.

**Extending to multiple days**

The above deals with the data for just a single day. The OP indicates he has six-months of daily entry/exit data, so the approach now needs to be extended to multiple days.

It is assumed that each data point (entry and exit value) is also assigned to a day. For simplicity, the days are assumed to be numbered as 1,2,... and that the data is organised into 3 columns: Day, Entry time, Exit time with 3 values for each row.The day column can be usefully labelled `Day`.

The entry times for day n are simply obtained by filtering out the values for day n. The `FILTER` function is used and the previous use of `Entry` is replaced by `FILTER(Entry,Day=n)`, so that the total entries for day n would now be written

`=BYCOL(N(FILTER(Entry,Day=n)=Time),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c)))`

and similarly for the totals for exits.

Using n as a reference to a cell containing the day number suggests that the daily profiles of persons can be structured as a large 2-dimensional range in which the first column lists the dates and each row contains a profile for a particular date.

**Practical issues**

1. The above will generalise fairly well to more than 8 hours and having range `Time` as 21 time values starting at 10:00am and stretching to 6:00am the following day is not an issue.
2. The time values in the entry/exit data need to be consistent with the values used in range `Time`. This is because the equality operator is used to generate the 1's and 0's that underpin the analysis. Mismatches caused by a mixture of text and formatted numbers will cause problems - stick to one or the other, preferably numbers and clean the data entry/exit data if necessary.
3. Similarly, having entry and exit times which are not within the set of `Time` values will give incorrect results. An entry time of say 10:59am or 11:01am will not get counted if the corresponding value in `Time` is 11:00am. Again, data cleaning may be necessary to avoid this problem.
4. To get good daily profiles, care needs to be taken to specifying the day number or date of the entry/exit points. The same date or day number should be used for time points after midnight as is used before. So for the opening period starting at (say) 10:00am on 01/07/2023, this same date should be used for any entry/exit values occurring on or prior to 06:00am on 02/07/2023.
5. Once the daily profiles have been obtained it would be sensible to assess whether the profiles vary according to day-of-week or time-of-year.